# Extract sentiment text using Solr

Tags: solr, sentiment-analysis

I have been searching on the web almost the whole day to try to find if there is a way to use Solr to do this. Basically I would like to extract positive and negative words from a given text and its frequency. Thanks in advance for your guidence!

Answer (score 0):

I think something like [Lingpipe](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/sentiment/read-me.html) would be more useful for sentiment analysis. You could probably adapt it to work with input from a Solr index.

Comment: Thanks! But i think Lingpipe needs a license. I first wonder if Solr can do this, disregard its quality for the task.

Comment: Weka, Mahout and other open-source machine learning libraries have sentiment analysis